# How to justify a number is the value of the function f?

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on the following problem in my real analysis class

Suppose that the function $f $  is continuous everywhere and

$f(0)=0, f(1)=5, and  \int_1^3  f(x) dx=-4$

Which real numbers are guaranteed to be values of the function $f$ ? Justify your answer.

I think the answer should be $f(3)=1$, since $f(1)+\int_1^3  f(x) dx = 1$, but I am struggling on justify this answer. I wanna use first fundamental theorem, but I can not prove this function is differentiable.

Additionally, is the $f(0)=0$ useful or not ?

Comment: Intermediate value theorem might be helpful; this theorem does not require differentiability.

Comment: $f(1)-\int_1^3  f(x) dx = 9$. Did you mean $f(1)+\int_1^3  f(x) dx = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

$f(0)=0$ tells you that $0$ is in the range of the function.  You are correct that $f(3)=1$ assuming the function is integrable, which we know because it is continuous.  Now use the intermediate value theorem based on the points you know.